# JBOSS_HOME in cloudbees?

Tags: jboss7.x, cloudbees

I am trying to build my project with Ant in the cloudbees environment. My application should be deployed on JBoss 7.x
My legacy build.xml was using JBOSS_HOME/module jars to compile source.
But how can refer to JBOSS_HOME with cloudbees. Is this env variable available ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no JBoss installation as you build your project on CloudBees DEV@Cloud. JBoss is only available as the application start, being deployed on RUN@Cloud